# Swapping elements in python list preserving both the initial and swapped list

Tags: python-3.x, list, methods, global-variables, swap

so I'm trying to swap 2 elements in a python list based on the position of 0 in the list and then compare the original list and the swapped list. I don't want it to be an in-place sorting and hence have created a new array named a which is equal to list. However, upon execution of my code which is given below my original list is also being changed due to the swap.

So, my code is given by :

```
list=[1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5]
a=list
def move_up(list):
    n=list.index(0)
    if n>2:
        list[n],list[n-3]=list[n-3],list[n]
    return list
```

Output is given by

```
print(move_up(a))
-> [1,0,3,8,2,4,7,6,5]

list
-> [1,0,3,8,2,4,7,6,5]
```

Expected Output is

```
print(move_up(a))
-> [1,0,3,8,2,4,7,6,5]

list
-> [1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5]
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not name a list 'list'. 'List' is a keyword in python. To solve your problem, You should do -

`a=ls.copy()`

If you don't, any changes made in list 'a' will reflect in changes made in the original list.

**Code**

```py
ls=[1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5]
a=ls.copy()
def move_up(list1):
    n=list1.index(0)
    if n>2:
        list1[n],list1[n-3]=list1[n-3],list1[n]
    return list1
```

**Output**

```py
>>print(move_up(a))
[1, 0, 3, 8, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5]

>>print(ls)
[1, 2, 3, 8, 0, 4, 7, 6, 5]
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it! It was because python lists use call by reference instead of value, right? Again, thanks for the help!